# Count occurrences with exclude criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, window-functions

I have a Table

```
City     ID
Austin   123
Austin   123
Austin   123
Austin   145
Austin   145
Chicago  12
Chicago  12
Houston  24
Houston  45
Houston  45
```

Now I want to count the occurrences of all Citis with different ids so since Chicago has only one id (=12) I am not interested in Chicago and it should not appear in the resultset that should looks like this:

```
city      Id   Occurrences
Austin   123   3
Austin   145   2
Houston   34   1
Houston   45   2
```

I am able to get myself an overview with

```
select city, Id from Table
group by city, Id
```

But I am not sure how to only select the once having different ids and to count them.

Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select city, id, occurences
from (
    select city, id, count(*) occurences, count(*) over(partition by city) cnt_city
    from mytable
    group by city, id
) t
where cnt_city > 1
```